# Removing 'white-space' of hidden images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a list of images that I would like to hide/show based on which `<li>` element is clicked. I have been able to do this successfully, however, there is still the white space below/above the image that is showing. Here is the code I am currently using:

HTML

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img id="img1" src="img/image1.jpg" />
    <img id="img2" src="img/image2.jpg" />
    <img id="img3" src="img/image3.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-container{
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

JS

```
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');
var img3 = document.getElementById('img3');

("li:nth-child(2)").on('click', function() {
    img1.style.visibility = 'visible';
    img2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    img3.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
("li:nth-child(3)").on('click', function(){
    img2.style.visibility = 'visible';
    img1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    img3.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
("li:last-child").on('click', function() {
    img3.style.visibility = 'visible';
    img2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    img1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
```

I have tried playing around with the `display: hidden` css property paired with `.toggle()` but cannot seem to quite get it working correctly. I have tried searching for this but cannot find anything on removing the white space the hidden image is holding. Am relatively new to JS/jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `display = 'block'` for visibility and `display = 'none'` to hide them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the css property `display` and values `none` and `block`.
The display property specifies if/how an element is displayed.

replace for visible img:

```
img1.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

for:

```
$("#img1").css("display", "block");
```

And replace for invisible img:

```
img1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

for:

```
$("#img1").css("display", "none");
```

Could use more useful `inline-block` instead `block` for lists.

Comment: Ended up going with this solution and it worked, thanks. I was also applying a `display: 'none'` to the `.img-container` class which was giving me problems, after removing that and implementing your solution everything works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When `visibility` is set to `hidden`, the element is not shown but still takes up space on the page.

When `display` is set to `none`, the element is neither shown nor does it take up any space on the page.

More often, I usually need:

```
display = 'none';
```

or

```
display = ''; // to have it show
```

Answer (score 0):

If looking for jQuery solution:

```js
var $img1 = $( "#img1" ),
    $img2 = $( "#img2" ),
    $img3 = $( "#img3" );

$( "li:nth-child(2)" ).on( "click", function() {
  $img1.show();
  $img2.hide();
  $img3.hide();
} );
$( "li:nth-child(3)" ).on( "click", function() {
  $img1.hide();
  $img2.show();
  $img3.hide();
} );
$( "li:nth-child(4)" ).on( "click", function() {
  $img1.hide();
  $img2.hide();
  $img3.show();
} );
$( "li:last-child" ).on( "click", function() {
  $img1.show();
  $img2.show();
  $img3.show();
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style="list-style: none;">
<li>Click a button:</li>
<li><button>Show First Photo</button></li>
<li><button>Show Second Photo</button></li>
<li><button>Show Thrid Photo</button></li>
<li><button>Reset</button></li>
</ul>

<div class="img-container">
  <img id="img1" width="300" height="300" src="https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/1.jpg" />
  <img id="img2" width="300" height="300" src="https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/2.jpg" />
  <img id="img3" width="300" height="300" src="https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/3.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `display` instead of `visibility` you could also consider making your JS a little easier to handle. You could simply show the `img` which has the same index as that of the clicked `li`.

EG:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".img-controller li").on("click", function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    $(".img-container img").hide();
    $(".img-container img:eq(" + i + ")").show();
  });
  $(".img-container img").not(":first").hide();
});
```

```css
.img-controller {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.img-controller li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="img-controller">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/40" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/30" />
</div>
```